# Perfect forwarding, why does the destructor get called twice?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a function that mimics Python's with statement but I've run into some interesting behavior that I don't quite understand.

With the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  foo() { std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
  ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo()" << std::endl; }
};

auto make_foo() -> foo {
  return {};
}

template <typename T, typename F>
auto with(T&& t, F&& fn) -> void {
  fn(std::forward<T>(t));
}

auto main() -> int {
  std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
  with(make_foo(), [](auto f) {
    std::cout << "during" << std::endl;
  });
  std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled under with the clang provided by Xcode 6.3 and `-std=c++14` and run I get the following output:

```
before
foo()
during
~foo()
~foo()
after
```

Does anybody know why I am getting two `~foo()`'s in my output?

Comment: Just curious, why do you write `auto main() -> int` instead of `int main()` ?

Comment: You don't really need a `with` equivalent in C++.

Comment: Hint: `auto` is *by value*, and is constructed from an rvalue

Comment: @Matt McNabb ah yes, silly oversight on my behalf... it's actually `foo(), foo(foo&&), during, ~foo(), ~foo()`, if you post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Vector Polevoy no reason other than aesthetics. now with modern c++ i find that some of my methods are forced to be the new auto -> ret-type format i prefer all of my functions to be like that for consistency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the two objects:

> `with(make_foo(), [](auto f) {`

```
      1^^^^^^^^^    2^^^^^^
```

There is the object returned by `make_foo()`, and the function argument `f`.

If you pass by reference (change to `auto&& f`) then you will only see evidence of one object.

There's no creation message because this is created by copy/move construction and you do not have any output in those constructors.

Note that there may be more objects inside `make_foo()` but your compiler is doing *copy elision*.

Comment: "*Note that there may be more objects inside make_foo() but your compiler is doing copy elision."*. I doubt that copy-list-initialization involves any more temporaries which a compiler would need to elide

Answer (score 3):

Your destructor calls don't appear to be matched with constructor calls simply because you aren't tracing copy/move constructors. If we add the tracing like so:

```
struct foo {
  foo() { std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
  ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo()" << std::endl; }
  foo(const foo&) { std::cout << "foo(const foo&)" << std::endl; }
  foo(foo&&) { std::cout << "foo(foo&&)" << std::endl; }
};
```

our output is now:

```
before
foo()
foo(foo&&)
during
~foo()
~foo()
after
```

The reason for the move-construction is that your lambda takes its parameter by value:

```
[](auto f) {
// ^^^^^^
    std::cout << "during" << std::endl;
}
```

If you don't want the copy, take by reference-to-const, or maybe even forwarding reference.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me by accepting an r-reference in the lambda function parameter to prevent a copy being made:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  foo() { std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
  ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo()" << std::endl; }
};

auto make_foo() -> foo {
  return {};
}

template <typename T, typename F>
auto with(T&& t, F&& fn) -> void {
  fn(std::forward<T>(t));
}

auto main() -> int {
  std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
  with(make_foo(), [](auto&&) { // r-reference!
    std::cout << "during" << std::endl;
  });
  std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

**New Improved Output:**

```
before
foo()
during
~foo()
after
```